# text-anchor="start" not moving text element to the start of the svg element.

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following really simple SVG code

```
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 194 186" class="circliful">
  <g stroke="#ccc">
    <line x1="133" y1="50" x2="140" y2="40" stroke-width="2"></line>
  </g>
  <g stroke="#ccc">
    <line x1="140" y1="40" x2="200" y2="40" stroke-width="2"></line>
  </g>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="57" class="border" fill="#eee" stroke="none" stroke-width="15" stroke-dasharray="360" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)"></circle>
  <circle class="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="57" fill="none" stroke="#3498DB" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="180, 20000" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)"></circle>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="110" class="icon" style="font-size: 40px" fill="#3498DB"></text>
  <text class="timer" text-anchor="middle" x="175" y="35" style="font-size: 22px; undefined;" fill="#aaa">50%</text>
</svg>

</div>
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/wynhn1ds/3/)**, My difficulty is regarding the following svg element and how the text-anchor attribute works with it:

```
<text class="timer" text-anchor="middle" x="175" y="35" style="font-size: 22px; undefined;" fill="#aaa">50%</text>
```

Now if i change `text-anchor="start"` , the text element does't really move to the start of the svg element, it rather moves to the start of the line below it , why ? can anybody explain why `text-anchor="start"` , is not working as expected ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text-anchor` is used to decide whether the X position of the text should be at the start, the end or in the middle of the text. To move the text position change it's X and Y coordinates.

To put the text at the start of the svg:

```
x="0"
text-anchor="start"
```

To put the text at the end of the svg:

```
x="194" //Width of the svg
text-anchor="end"
```

To put the text in the middle of the svg:

```
x="97" //Half of the width of the svg
text-anchor="middle"
```

Comment: Brilliant.. Brilliant ... Brilliant !!